# Hide correct CpS Information in Subtitle Workshop

Tags: video

I was fine tuning subtitles I've made with Subtitle Workshop and after finished I saved and closed the program as usual but then I remembered there was one last thing I needed to do.

When I opened it again I think I used some keyboard shortcut by accident because those CpS informations that appear on the right of each line are now being displayed in all subtitles, even those defined correctly.

And this is somewhat disturbing because I use those informations while editing to know if I need, for example, to use a synonym with less characters in order to reach the standard defined. But if all lines have the info shown, mentally, I have to read if the percentage value is greater than 100% or not and then proceed with the adjustment, making the whole process even more exhausting than it is (due my own extreme criticism >.<)

How can I revert it to default, only displaying info about the really wrong ones (greater than 100%, more CpS than  allowed...)

Comment: Note: Question tagged wrongly due lack of option available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if there is indeed a keyboard shortcut for this, but reading carefully the *SubtitleWorkshop.ini* settings file I've found:

```
Show CPS hint boxes=1
```

I tried to find it through program interface and since I couldn't, I've set it manually to 0 (zero) and all information, correct and incorrect, error or warning, disappeared.

Then, through *Information and error* settings (default to Alt+I), under **Mark** tab, I checked only the option *Mark too much CpS boxes* in the very bottom and then only the really wrong ones appeared again.

Here, a screenshot:

[image: a screenshot]

I hope it helps someone else ;)

Answer (score -1):

you must try click Alt + H to hide these correct cps information.